# Alacritty terminal text is always the same color

Tags: terminal, yaml, color-scheme, alacritty

I've started configuring my `alacritty.yml` file, making adjustments such as customizing the window dimensions, setting the font style to FiraCode (even though I didn't find how to set ligatures on), and applying a theme from [tokyo-night](https://github.com/zatchheems/tokyo-night-alacritty-theme/tree/main). However, I'm encountering an issue where my terminal text is consistently white, and the overall interface doesn't look like I want.

I've seen others have different symbols for actions like searching (e.g., "~" or "->"), and distinct colors based on the type of action being performed. I aspire for my theme to resemble the ones from [here](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty-theme). I've searched and found if you configure the `PS1` in `bashrc` will do the job, but dosen't seem to do anything.
Here is my `alacritty.yml` file:

```
window:
  dimensions:
    columns: 999
    lines: 999

  padding:
    x: 0
    y: 0
  title: Shefu
  dynamic_padding: true
  decorations: full
  startup_mode: Windowed 
  opacity: 1.0

font:
  normal:
    family: FiraCode Nerd Font
    style: Retina

  bold:
    family: FiraCode Nerd Font
    style: Bold

  italic:
    family:  FiraCode Nerd Font
    style: Italic

  size: 12.0
    
custom_cursor_colors: true

schemes:
  tokyo-night: &tokyo-night
    # Default colors
    primary:
      background: '#1a1b26'
      foreground: '#a9b1d6'
    # Normal colors
    normal:
      black:   '#32344a'
      red:     '#f7768e'
      green:   '#9ece6a'
      yellow:  '#e0af68'
      blue:    '#7aa2f7'
      magenta: '#ad8ee6'
      cyan:    '#449dab'
      white:   '#787c99'

    # Bright colors
    bright:
      black:   '#444b6a'
      red:     '#ff7a93'
      green:   '#b9f27c'
      yellow:  '#ff9e64'
      blue:    '#7da6ff'
      magenta: '#bb9af7'
      cyan:    '#0db9d7'
      white:   '#acb0d0'

  tokyo-night-storm: &tokyo-night-storm
    # Default colors
    primary:
      background: '#24283b'
      foreground: '#a9b1d6'

    # Normal colors
    normal:
      black:   '#32344a'
      red:     '#f7768e'
      green:   '#9ece6a'
      yellow:  '#e0af68'
      blue:    '#7aa2f7'
      magenta: '#ad8ee6'
      cyan:    '#449dab'
      white:   '#9699a8'

    # Bright colors
    bright:
      black:   '#444b6a'
      red:     '#ff7a93'
      green:   '#b9f27c'
      yellow:  '#ff9e64'
      blue:    '#7da6ff'
      magenta: '#bb9af7'
      cyan:    '#0db9d7'
      white:   '#acb0d0'
colors: *tokyo-night
cursor:
  style:
    shape: Beam
    blinking: Off

selection:
  save_to_clipboard: false

live_config_reload: true
```